# Installing windows xp on a SATA drive computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp

My laptop make is Lenovo,model is Z580.
It has i5-3210m and 500 GB HDD.Also,it has nvidia geforce gt 630m GPU.System memory is 4GB.

I wanted to dual boot windows xp with the other OSes,currently present in it(windows 7,Ubuntu,Kali).I know that if I change it to IDE,it will work.But I don't want to change it.I Googled and got this article " m.wikihow.com/Slipstream-Your-SATA-Drivers-Into-a-Windows-XP-Installation-CD-Using-nLite  ".But I am confused on a point,why only " f6flpy3286 .zip"  ? Will it work for my controller?

Sorry,for bad English.

Comment: You tell us.  What SATA controller does your computer use?  The archive file is the driver for the Mobile Intel® ICH9M SATA controller. You might as well attempt it, you have nothing to lose, because anything you do can be reversed.  Furthermore if Windows XP is already installed you can simply provide the driver to see if the device will accept the driver.

Comment: Moreover, slipstreaming incorrect driver won't break anything. It just won't work.

Comment: also augh. Don't run XP on real hardware on a modern system. Makes *much* more sense to run it as a VM

Comment: How to know that?What SATA controller
does my computer use?

Comment: Okay.I used a software.I noticed that chipset controller  model is Intel HM76.Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I was looking through an article in wiki and noticed this line-" Intel's Core i7 and Core i5 CPUs
have an integrated memory controller
(IMC) on the microprocessor in order to
reduce memory latency."Link to that web page is " en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller ".So,does it mean-my Intel HM76 is the only chipset which can also work as a SATA controller?If yes,then what driver should I use?Please help me by giving the direct download link to the appropriate driver.Please.I beg you. :'(

Comment: Assuming this matches your hardware: " f6flpy3286 .zip"  is a compressed file when you unzip it the necessary files will be extracted and made visible. I can not find any XP compatible drivers on the intel site.

Comment: Okay.Thanks.But I already fixed it." www.win-raid.com/t22f23-Integration-of-Intels-AHCI-RAID-drivers-into-a-Windows-XP-CD.html "-this site contains all the drivers. :-)